# SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA never fires in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flex3

microphone.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, gotMicData);
the event gotMicData is never fired.. however i tried using dispatchEvent but that will return null byteArray..
However similar code works fine in Flashcs5...

```
        import flash.events.SampleDataEvent;
        import flash.media.Microphone;
        import flash.media.Sound;
        import flash.utils.ByteArray;

        [Bindable] private var microphoneList:Array;
                 protected var microphone:Microphone;
                 protected var isRecording:Boolean = false;
                 protected var soundRecording:ByteArray;
                 protected var soundOutput:Sound;

        protected function setupMicrophoneList():void
        {
            microphoneList = Microphone.names;
        }

        protected function setupMicrophone():void
        {
            microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone(comboMicList.selectedIndex);
            microphone.rate = 44;
        }

        protected function startMicRecording():void
        {
            isRecording = true;
            soundRecording = new ByteArray();
            microphone.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, gotMicData);
        }

        protected function stopMicRecording():void
        {
            isRecording = false;
            microphone.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, gotMicData);
        }

        private function gotMicData(micData:SampleDataEvent):void
        {
            soundRecording.writeBytes(micData.data);
        }

        protected function playbackData():void
        {
            soundRecording.position = 0;

            soundOutput = new Sound();
            soundOutput.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playSound);

            soundOutput.play();
        }

        private function playSound(soundOutput:SampleDataEvent):void
        {
            if (!soundRecording.bytesAvailable > 0)
                return;
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192; i++)
            {
                var sample:Number = 0;
                if (soundRecording.bytesAvailable > 0)
                    sample = soundRecording.readFloat();
                soundOutput.data.writeFloat(sample); 
                soundOutput.data.writeFloat(sample);  
            }               
        }


    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Comment: It would be unusual to make a private var Bindable, but I doubt that relates to your current issue.  It is not obvious to me that "startMicRecording" is ever called.  If it isn't, then your listener is never added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the Flex Builder will also set sdk 3.2 as default and I found that u just have to download the latest flex sdk and use it in flex builder.. and the code will work fine..

Comment: Still can not launch the similar code - SampleDataEvent simply didn't fire (Flex SDK 4.1)...

Comment: i would suggest try using flash builder 4 as it uses sdk 4.1 by default. it is the sdk problem that the event does not fire.

Answer (score 0):

SampleDataEvent is a Flash player 10.1 feature. Set your player target to 10.1 or higher in the Flex Compiler properties for your project, and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Just to add to this thread I was having a similar problem until I saw a comment on this blog :

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1858

Basically you have to make sure your stage is big enough to accommodate the flash security settings window.

Drove me nuts trying to figure this beauty out.